# Fill null values with the Last not null using Last_value()

Tags: postgresql

I have this table and I have to fill value with the last not null value. Null value can be consecutive (one or more than one).

```
|    date    | value |
+------------+-------+
| 2021-01-05 | NULL  |
| 2021-01-04 | NULL  |
| 2021-01-03 | 3     |
| 2021-01-02 | NULL  |
| 2021-01-01 | 1     |
+------------+-------+
```

expected result

```
|    date    | value |
+------------+-------+
| 2021-01-05 | 3     |
| 2021-01-04 | 3     |
| 2021-01-03 | 3     |
| 2021-01-02 | 1     |
| 2021-01-01 | 1     |
+------------+-------+
```

I have tried with this but it doesn't work with two consecutive null values. How can I set the range from the last not null to current rows?
How to do if the first value is NULL (eg. 2020-12-31 IS null) ?

```
SELECT

    date, 
    last_VALUE(val) 
        OVER(
            PARTITION BY scope_field
            ORDER BY date desc
            RANGE BETWEEN '1 day' PRECEDING AND '1 day' FOLLOWING
        ) last_val
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_agg()` window function:

```
SELECT date,
       COALESCE(value, values[array_upper(values, 1)]::int) AS value
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         array_agg(value::varchar) FILTER (WHERE value IS NOT NULL) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS values
  FROM tablename    
) t  
ORDER BY date DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=959036ad2597a76d5a93316c702c56ab).

Comment: There is a problem if there is a NULL in the middle. It gets 5 instead of 1. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6cb8187b6e16cd8fa4771f890b5eeea8

Comment: @sparkle you are right. Check my edited answer.