# PostgreSQL- Fill previous values with first non-null

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have 2 tables on my db:
1- scheduled services
2- services realized.

On 2nd table, I have the value $ received for the service and the date the service was realized.
On 1st table, I only have the scheduled dates without values.

The point is:
Sometimes the scheduled service can't be done, and it have to be re-scheduled, so the realized date can be different than the scheduled date.
But, even when the service wasn't realized, I want to know how much $ was scheduled every day.
I've created a view (vw_test) that looks like:

```
vw_test:
SELECT
    t1.date,
    t1.service,
    t2.value
FROM
    scheduled AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    realized AS t2
ON CONCAT(t1.date, t1.service) = CONCAT(t2.date, t2.service)
ORDER BY
    t1.service ASC,
    t2.date ASC
```

vw_test:

| date | service | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-02 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-03 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-04 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-05 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-06 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-07 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-08 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-09 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-10 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-01 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-02 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-03 | B | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-04 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-05 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-06 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-07 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-08 | B | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-09 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-10 | B | Null |

I'm trying to fill the Null values with the next Non-Null value and keep Null for values after the Non-Null value for every service, like the table below:

| date | service | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-02 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-03 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-04 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-05 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-06 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-07 | A | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-08 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-09 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-10 | A | Null |
| 2023-04-01 | B | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-02 | B | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-03 | B | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-04 | B | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-05 | B | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-06 | B | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-07 | B | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-08 | B | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-09 | B | Null |
| 2023-04-10 | B | Null |

Is that possible to achieve with PostgreSQL?
I've tried ARRAY_AGG like mentioned in [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214524/fill-null-values-with-the-last-not-null-using-last-value)
and JSONB_AGG [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462304/postgresql-forward-fill-null-values-with-previous-not-null-value-in-group)
but the result is the same as the vw_test.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a gaps-and-islands approach for this.

I know that `vw_test` is a view for you.  I simplified my example by making it a table:

```
with realizeds as (
  select *, 
         (value is null and lag(value) over w is not null)::int as realized
    from vw_test 
  window w as (partition by service order by date)
), islands as (
  select *, 
         sum(realized) over w as group_num
    from realizeds
  window w as (partition by service order by date)
)
select *, max(value) over w as realized_value
  from islands
window w as (partition by service order by date
          rows between current row and unbounded following);
```

I left the intermediate columns in there to illustrate how the query works.

[Working example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/3h-wt8JZ)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with window functions:

```
select date, service, value, max(value) over(partition by service, grp) as new_value
from (
    select t.*, count(value) over(partition by service order by date desc) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
order by service, date
```

The idea is to build groups of rows that contain a single rows with a non-`null` value, optionnaly preceded by any number of rows with `null` values: that's what the window `count` in the subquery does.

All that is then left to do is to re-assign the (only) non-`null` value of the group to each row of the group.

| date | service | value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | A | *null* | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-02 | A | *null* | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-03 | A | *null* | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-04 | A | *null* | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-05 | A | *null* | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-06 | A | *null* | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-07 | A | 150.80 | 150.80 |
| 2023-04-08 | A | *null* | *null* |
| 2023-04-09 | A | *null* | *null* |
| 2023-04-10 | A | *null* | *null* |
| 2023-04-01 | B | *null* | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-02 | B | *null* | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-03 | B | 247.17 | 247.17 |
| 2023-04-04 | B | *null* | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-05 | B | *null* | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-06 | B | *null* | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-07 | B | *null* | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-08 | B | 75.12 | 75.12 |
| 2023-04-09 | B | *null* | *null* |
| 2023-04-10 | B | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6aEZ5dgt)